# Magento translation of configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, customer-attribute, translate

I am using pickpack to print a PDF sheet of the purchase but it is using from Catalog/Attribute/Manage Attribute/"the name of the attribute"/Manage Label/Option and not from Admin but from the Default Store View. I know that from the Manage products you could enabled the tickbox to use default.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should contact "PickPack" and ask them. It's impossible for us to help you if we cannot see the code.